# Send decimal values by WebClient getting Nothing on Controller

Tags: vb.net, winforms, asp.net-web-api, webclient

I'm having a problem trying to send a WebClient request with decimal values like `7.8` to a WebApi from a Windows Form Application. When I try to access this values on Controller of the WebApi, this values are `Nothing`.

Here is my model:

```
Public Class ProductModel
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Quantity As Decimal?
    Public Property Price As Decimal?
End Class
```

Here is my request function on my Windows Form Application:

```
Public Function SendProduct() As String    
        Using client As New WebClient
            client.Headers.Clear()
            client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            client.Encoding = Text.Encoding.UTF8

            Dim params As New Specialized.NameValueCollection

            params.Add("Name", "Product 1")
            params.Add("Quantity", CDec(7.0))
            params.Add("Price", CDec(7.8))

            Dim responseBytes As Byte() = client.UploadValues("http://localhost:50305/mycontroller/sendproduct", "POST", params)
            Dim response As String = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(responseBytes)

            Return response
        End Using
End Function
```

Here is my action on Controller:

```
<HttpPost>
Public Function SendProduct(<FromBody> model As ProductModel) As IHttpActionResult   
    'At this point my model values are:
    'model.Name = "Product 1"
    'model.Quantity = 7
    'model.Price = Nothing (Here is the problem)
End Function
```

Note that the Quantity is decimal too and it was send correctly

Tks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what is the problem. The value that I add on `NameValueCollection` is parsed to string in runtime, so when decimal values is added the value change to "7,8" where the comma is the problem. For test I just do `CDec(7.8).ToString().Replace(",", ".")` and it works. So now I'm changing to another way to send the data correctly.

Tks anyway guys!